# Refer to a multiline String variable from fx:define block

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I defined multiline String variable in `fx:define`:

```
<fx:define>
    <String fx:id="LABEL_01" fx:value="${'liczba czytelników\nzarejestrowanych'}"/>
</fx:define>
```

Now I wish to refer to it in `Label`. How to do this using `LABEL_01` as a `text` value? This doesn't work:

```
<Label text="$LABEL_01"/>
```

Wish to mention that this piece of code works:

```
<Label text="${'liczba czytelników\nzarejestrowanych'}"/>
```

Java code also works (why shouldn't it?):

```
Label labelLiczbaCzytelnikowZarejestrowanych = new Label("liczba czytelników\nzarejestrowanych");
```

but I want do it in FXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wish to mention that this piece of code works:
>
> ```xml
> <Label text="${'liczba czytelników\nzarejestrowanych'}"/>
> ```

This probably isn't working like you think it is.

The `${}` syntax is an [expression binding](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding). This *binds* the target property (`text`) to the expression between the `{}`. As your expression is a `'string'` you are using a *string constant*. When parsing the expression it will interpret the `\n` as a newline character. Basically, a *string constant* is treated the same as a *string literal* in Java code.

<sup>*Note: You can see the `text` property is bound by injecting the `Label` into a controller and querying `textProperty().isBound()`.*</sup>

Some equivalent Java code would be:

```java
Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty()
        .bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "liczba czytelników\nzarejestrowanych"));
```

---

> ```xml
> <String fx:id="LABEL_01" fx:value="${'liczba czytelników\nzarejestrowanych'}"/>
> ```

The `${}` syntax has no special meaning in the context of `fx:value`. What this does is create the target type (`String`) using the class' static `valueOf(String)` method. The argument for the `valueOf` method is the literal value as defined by the `fx:value` attribute. This means the expression binding syntax and the `\n` are used as is. The `\n` is literally a backslash followed by an "n", same as using `"\\n"` in Java.

---

An FXML file is, at its core, just an XML file. As far as I can tell, the FXML format provides no special multi-line support outside of *string constants* in an expression binding. However, you can use XML escapes to insert newline characters (i.e. [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54198990/6395627)).

Answer (score 1):

I can use `&#xD;` to solve multiline problem in FXML.

```
<fx:define>
    <String fx:id="LABEL_01" fx:value="liczba czytelników&#xD;zarejestrowanych'}"/>
</fx:define>
```

Then I can use this code to refer `LABEL_01`:

```
<Label text="$LABEL_01"/>
```

This is one of solutions, but I still would like to know how to refer to variable `"${'liczba czytelników\nzarejestrowanych'}"`?